# nc (netcat) миллисекундное ожидание

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, netcat

Есть список серверов которые нужно "прозвонить" **nc** (пинг не доступен) как задать параметру **-w** миллисекундное значение?

```
-w timeout
    If a connection and stdin are idle 
    for more than timeout seconds, then 
    the connection is silently closed.
```

Это часть "факта" для Ansilbe в наличие до 10 серверов которые нужно проверить от каждого управляемого нода (до 3000), если ждать по секунде на каждом получится 10 х 3000 секунд простоя.

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc

Comment: Меня одно время интересовал такой же вопрос, но дальше, чем «надо патчить», дело не дошло.

Comment: если вы хотите с каждого из 3000 узлов обратиться к 10 серверам (tcp connect() или что-то другое?), то почему «10 х 3000 секунд простоя»? Что мешает одновременно на разных узлах команды запускать? Что мешает на одном узле более одного соединения открыть одновременно?

Comment: @jfs ночью писал вопрос :-), обработка идет параллельно по 100.

Comment: nmap тут рулит. есть и распаралеливание и простая проверка tcp-syn

Comment: @eri. Глянул получше, нужно ограничеть время ожидания если сервер не доступен до 0.1с

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел обертку через **timeout** (GNU coreutils)

Немного тестов:

```
~$ time nc -vzw1 8.8.8.8 53 || echo "down or notactive"
Connection to 8.8.8.8 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!

real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

~$ time nc -vzw1 8.8.8.3 53 || echo "down or not active"
nc: connect to 8.8.8.3 port 53 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
down or not active

~$ time timeout 0.1 nc -vzw1 8.8.8.8 53 || echo "down or not active"
Connection to 8.8.8.8 53 port [tcp/domain] succeeded!

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

~$ time timeout 0.1 nc -vzw1 8.8.8.3 53 || echo "down or not active"

real    0m0.101s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
down or not active
```

И рабочий bash скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
SERVER_LIST_PATH="/home/login_user/server_list"

server_active()
{
    [ -e /tmp/srv_active ] && rm /tmp/srv_active

    while read -r srv; do
        timeout 0.1 nc -vz "$(echo "$srv" | tr ':' ' ')" &>/dev/null
        if [[ "$?" = 0 ]]; then
            echo "$srv" > /tmp/srv_active
        fi
    done < "$SERVER_LIST_PATH"

    if [[ -e /tmp/srv_active ]]; then
        printf '%d' "$(wc -l /tmp/srv_active)"
    else
        printf '0'
    fi

    [ -e /tmp/srv_active ] && rm /tmp/srv_active
}

main()
{
    server_active
}

main "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

`nc -w` не поддерживает миллисекунды. Глядя на [netcat-openbsd реализацию](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/544a6830f617e4313b93d25d06e5d147a9a10c2d/usr.bin/nc/netcat.c#L284-L289):

```c
    case 'w':
        timeout = strtonum(optarg, 0, INT_MAX / 1000, &errstr);
        if (errstr)
            errx(1, "timeout %s: %s", errstr, optarg);
        timeout *= 1000;
        break;
```

то есть `-w` принимает целое число секунд и превращает их в миллисекунды (но другие части кода, также могут ожидать только целые секунды).

В зависимости от того, что вы хотите сделать, можно это реализовать используя другие утилиты такие как socat, nmap.

Comment: Спасибо за socat,  читаю док. Нужно собрать метрики что все 10 серверов доступны для нода на 3346 порту, проверяю тем самым активность самих серверов и VPN тоннелей на фаерволе через который идет к ним доступ.

Comment: Обернул через ```timeout 0.1 nc -vz server.com 443```